# Changing some of the language within the revision viewer admin page revision.php

Tags: custom-post-types, language

I have a custom post type, to which the term "post" is irelevent.  I had managed via various hooks to change all references of "post" to something else in the main post editing pages.   I suddenly enabled revision support in my custom post and then realised that some text on the revision page needs updating.

I haven't been able to find a quick and fairly easy way to do this though.   It's really small things like the link top left of the page that currently states "Return to post editor".

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this in the end with some careful jQuery code that is run via a new JS file that is only loaded via the admin system pages.

To give an example of the jQuery code...

```
jQuery('.wrap a').each(function() {
    if ( getCurentFileName()=="revision.php" ){
        var text = jQuery(this).text();
        jQuery(this).text(text.replace('← Return to post editor', '← the new replacement text'));
    }
});

function getCurentFileName(){
   var pagePathName= window.location.pathname;
   return pagePathName.substring(pagePathName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
}
```